# QuickFIX/J - how to handle End Of Stream

Tags: quickfixj

I am new to QuickFIX/J.

Creating initiator using websocket(frontend-angular, backend-Springboot websocket). Using w.3.

I would like to handle session expired issue. When the FIX server session is expired, it is sending Logout with reason session deactivated. That works fine for already connected connection/session.

Now, after this, trying to initiate connection, it keeps calling back logout and toAdmin with repeating event/error on screen log (as event) "Disconnecting, End Of Stream encountered".

I would like to handle this scenario and want to capture this in my code so that proper message to UI will be sent.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which QuickFIX/J version you are using, but on versions up to 2.2.0 you could implement the `quickfix.SessionStateListener` in your application and utilize its `onDisconnect()` callback.

If you are even using version 2.3.0 you could also use `onConnectException()` which will handle some additional scenarios that the first callback does not cover.

Comment: Hey,I am using 2.3.0. I have also created new class which implements the SessionStateListener. And in my ClientApp, in onCreate method, I have added it like Session.lookupSession(sessionId).addStateListtener(new StatelistenerImpl());     now I had implemented only onConnectException() -》logout session and send message to UI.Hope that works.

Comment: Yes,it worked..I had to give implementation of disconnect() too.

Answer (score 0):

Should it be something like:

```
public class SessionListener implements SessionStateListener {

@Override
public void onDisconnect() {
    SessionStateListener.super.onDisconnect();
   // add our custom code
}

@Override
public void onConnect() {
    SessionStateListener.super.onConnect();
    // add our custom code
}
}
```

The above will not work without adding the implementation class to the session as follows:

```
Session.lookupSession(sessionID).addStateListener(new SessionListener());
```

This is inside the following method of the class that extends MessageCracker and implements Application

```
@Override
public void onCreate(SessionID sessionID) {
```

Comment: I don't think you need to call super() but yes, that is the SessionStateListener I mentioned. Don't forget to implement `onConnectException()`.